# Toolbar hiding on rotated UISplitView DetailView

Tags: uitableview, uitoolbar, ipad

I've based my app on Apple's SplitView project type.  I have a TableView as the Master, and am using different types of views as the Detail view.  To select types of detail view, I'm using the fancy concept of buttons on my DetailView toolbar.  When the DetailView is derived from UIViewController, everything is good.  When the DetailView derives from UIViewController, but contains a UITableView then I have problems.  In portrait view the toolbar is visible.  In landscape mode the toolbar is hidden, even though the Tableview is moved down to allow space for it.  The UIToolbar and UITableView are both defined in my NIB file which is loaded to create the detail view.  Why is my toolbar invisible in landscape?

BTW, is this the best way to choose Detail view types with UISplitView?  Bonus question, what if selecting a row in my DetailView tableview should bring up another View, I can't push it like I would with a NaviagtionController, so how do I go back to the detail tableview?

Thanks, Gerry

Answer (score 4):

HI Gerry,
I have faced the same toolbar problem, when trying to rotate the splitView, toolbar will disappear. If you are creating the toolbar in the interface builder, try to set the toolbar properties(size), by selecting the toolbar, then --> Tools -->Size inspector, in the autosizing section, mark the left, right and upper red lines and unmark the bottom red line, then everything will works fine.

-Maria

Answer (score 0):

1. Bonus question, I would create a UINavigationController in code, set it's rootcontroller to the DetailView tableview (self) and then push the new view on top of it.
2. When you react to the rotation change are you using the same view or a different one for the detail view? Seems like the new view may not contain an instance of the toolbar? Or the Tableview is covering it up because the landscape view has less vertical room than the portrait view. Are you resetting the height of the tableview to allow space for the toolbar within the 768 height when rotating to landscape?

Just a tip but whenever I run into odd things like this I remove the elements from the NIB file and create them programmatically in code and it usually solves the problem. You get a lot more control over things when you do. Overall as I've gained more experience with programming for iPhone OS I've found that I rarely put much into a NIB file any longer and do almost everything in code now.

Comment: I'm using the same detalview in both portrait and landscape.  My tableview is leaving space at the top for the toolbar, but this space is currently being filled with white.  I would prefer not to use the nib, but I found that using the nib was the only way I could get a toolbar at all.  (Toolbar is in the nib as is the tableview.)  I was not able to figure it out in straight code.

Comment: This article solves the problem.  It shows how to create a useful splitview application.

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/